# Set security policy applet in Eclipse Java

Tags: java, eclipse, security, applet, policy

I have applet which I run in command line like this:

```
appletviewer -J-Djava.security.policy=="java.policy.applet" stronka.html
```

and I want to run applet from Eclipse with enabled security policy. I know that I have to set this here:

Run -> Run Configurations menu.
Right click "Java Applet" and choose "New".
Give your run configuration a name.
Select your project and the applet class.
Choose the "arguments" tab and enter your security policy VM argument.

But what exactly in my case, I have to add there?

Comment: A policy file will not work for an applet in production.  You might as well create a certificate, and sign the Jar with it when, while it is being built.

Comment: It is only for study perpouses, maybe I didn't said that but using cmd with above command everything work fine, but using eclipse, user has permissions which are note granted in policy. So the question is how to run this applet via eclipse with specified policy

Comment: I added the Eclipse tag, but feel you are better off spending your time learning how to *"create a certificate"* during the Eclipse build.  Good luck with it.